# Why is component-out showing up greyscale?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

I'm trying to hook up a laptop to a projector with a component (red, green, & blue RCA) cable. The laptop has one of those combo mini-DIN ports, with an adapter that re-routes those connections to S-Video and component plugs. This adapter works fine with one of my laptops and a desktop, meaning all the cables and such involved are known to work.

However, when plugged into the Dell Inspiron 1525 we need to use, the image on the projector is greyscale. This happens under both Win8 and XP, and the issue has been narrowed down to this specific laptop.

Is there anything in particular that could cause this output to go greyscale? And moreover, is there something I can do to rectify the problem?

Comment: Grayscale output means the projector is getting the luma (brightness) signal, but not the chroma (color) signal, so it knows how bright each pixel should be but not what color to make it. Dumb question, but: Are you sure you've got the cables hooked up to the projector's component input? I ask because what you're seeing could easily be produced by plugging the Y (luma) component into a composite video input, which expects chroma and luma on the same cable -- if it's only getting luma, then it will produce a grayscale image.

Comment: It could also mean that your laptop is outputting a composite signal into your component input. Have you tried the laptop with a known good display, and tried a known good source on this display?

Comment: Yes, when *only* the laptop is switched out (cables left plugged in, everything still turned on), a different model laptop produces a color display on the projector. It seems like the laptop is just acting in S-Video mode, but it has the same 7-pin combo port as other devices.